# What trigger the support logs in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, rhel

I see in our server, each day the support folder under `JENKINS-HOME` folder is getting full with large logs:

```
jenkins/jenkins-production/support> ll
total 3.2G
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins aimsys 906M Jan  8 13:44 support_2020-01-08_04.08.06.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins aimsys 977M Jan 16 17:30 support_2020-01-16_08.33.06.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins aimsys 1.1G Jan 26 17:52 support_2020-01-26_07.05.51.zip
```

I'm trying to understand where is it coming from. I saw there is configuration page in Jenkins for support:

```
http://illinXXXX:18080/view/YYYY/support/
```

but I didn't understand what triggers it. Did anyone face it?

Comment: I think it comes from Support Core Plugin: 
The plugin provides the basic infrastructure for generating "bundles" of support information within Jenkins.

There are three ways of generating bundles:

Automatic bundles, these get saved in $JENKINS_HOME/support once per hour starting 3 minutes after Jenkins starts the plugin (i.e. this may still be generated even if Jenkins will not fully start). The automatic bundles are retained using an exponential aging strategy, so you should have a bunch of them over the entire lifetime once the plugin has been installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to disable to Support Core Plugin